# Unable to logout from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in laravel(using version 8) and working on "Logout section" but unable to logout,still getting
email in session (after logout),How can i logout ?
Here is my view file

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}">
<i class="typcn typcn-power text-primary"></i>
    Logout
</a>
```

Here is my Routes(web.php)

```
Route::get('logout', [AdminController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
```

Here is my controller code,How can i logout ? Thank you in advance.

```
function logout()
    {
        Auth()->logout();
        return redirect('/')->with('logout_message', 'You have been logged out');;
    }
```

Comment: You should use `POST` for the logout route.

Comment: Change to a POST route and use a form, not a button for logout.  If you do not, a browser pre-fetching content might log your user out and you will be scratching your head why.  Not to mention that it is poorer security to use a get route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not only logout, but also invalidate the session.

Use something like this, from [the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#logging-out):

> ```php
> use Illuminate\Http\Request;
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
>  
> /**
>  * Log the user out of the application.
>  *
>  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
>  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
>  */
> public function logout(Request $request)
> {
>     Auth::logout();
>  
>     $request->session()->invalidate();
>  
>     $request->session()->regenerateToken();
>  
>     return redirect('/');
> }
> ```